# get the resident memory of indivdual threads of a process using bash shell

Tags: bash, ram

If I want to find the resident memory a process uses, I might use something like "ps aux | grep apache2" or "sudo pmap -d 1130". However, I have one process that has 25 threads, and I would like to know how much resident memory (excluding the shared process memory) each of those threads are consuming, as well as showing the total number of threads for that process. I would like to do this in the bash shell. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads share memory by definition. Therefore threads do not have individual memory and will not contribute to virtual and resident memory. It is possible to allocate memory from within a thread, but the kernel has no information about what memory is allocated for which thread, and so it is impossible to query for this from outside the process.